# Refreshing a PHP query page with pure javascript (location.reload) reruns the query a second time

Tags: php, mysql

**the new comment added is not displayed unless refreshed**
so i add h2 tag if the query is run to refresh the page through javascript but it increments the query

```
$query2=mysqli_query($con,"insert into comments(comment,user_id,bpid)     values('".$comment."','".$realuserid."','".$blogid."')");

  if($query2){

    $cerror= "<h2 id='refreshdiv'>comment added click here to view the comment</div>";
  }
```

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
var comment= document.getElementById("refreshdiv");
function refresh(){
   location.reload();
 }
 comment.onclick = refresh;
```

but has i click the h2 element the query(comment) is added the second time

and

the header(h2) is not hiddden after click

**---------here is the link to the complete file if anyone can help me   http://codepad.org/tGzLghiK**

Comment: what are you trying to do ? i dont see any need of mysql here

Comment: because you are executing query every time

Comment: can you look at the file link PHP code see whats wrong

Comment: you are doing it all wrong your code is vulnerable to sql injection and XSS

Comment: why you doing that `$blogid =$_GET['bpid'];` when you are assigning the $blogid in if-else

Comment: i would strongly suggest you to read articles here http://shiflett.org/articles

Comment: blog page url is xyz.com/blogmain.php?bpid=1

Comment: **I am novice in Backend-coding just need a work around to finish my site**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64683/discussion-between-sachin-hd-and-obi-nullpoite-kenobi).